# How to use a SQLAlchemy scoped_session in a context manager?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Per [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html), we should use the following pattern with a `sessionmaker` object:

```
Session = sessionmaker(engine)
with Session.begin() as session:
    session.add(some_object)
```

In a multithreaded environment, we are also supposed to use a single `scoped_session` and share it. So in my `__init__.py` I create create one and import it everywhere else in my program:

```
engine = create_engine(config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

The question is, how am I supposed to combine these two approaches? This seems to be the suggested way, but it errors out:

```
from myapp import Session
with Session.begin() as session:
    query_result = session.query(MyModel).all()

----
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'SessionTransaction' object has no attribute 'query'
```

I tried the following and it works, but it seems like it doesn't follow the docs, and I'm afraid it breaks something not obvious. **Can anyone confirm if this is correct?**

```
from myapp import Session
with Session() as session, session.begin():
    query_result = session.query(MyModel).all()
```

I've been looking around at other replies and seeing very little that addresses the specific question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`Session.begin()` docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.begin):

> The `Session` object features autobegin behavior, so that normally it is not necessary to call the `Session.begin()` method explicitly. However, it may be used in order to control the scope of when the transactional state is begun.

You can use `Session.begin()` (new in 1.4) to obtain a [`SessionTransaction`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.SessionTransaction) instance usable as a context manager which will autocommit on successful exit.

Calling the `scoped_session` returns a `SessionTransaction` right away, as per your error, so you do not need to begin it again.

All in all, you can definitely do the stacked context manager, but its unnecessary, so you might as well stick to using the [original flow](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/contextual.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications):

```py
Session = scoped_session(...)

with Session() as session:  # NB. session is a thread local SessionTransaction
    ...
    session.commit()
```

or the proxied `Session`

```py
Session = scoped_session(...)

@on_request_end
def remove_session(req):
    Session.remove()

@route("/xyz", ...)
def handle_xyz():
    instance = Class(...)
    Session.add(instance)
    Session.commit()
```